# OpenCV PCA not initializable

Tags: opencv, constructor, initialization, pca

Given http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

PCA should be initializable by just passing it a matrix.

```
cv::Mat matrix;
...
//If I do
cv::PCA pca;
pca(matrix);
```

I get the error, that function `cv::PCA::operator() cannot be called with the given arguments`

And if I do:

```
cv::PCA pca(matrix);
```

it says "no instance of constructor matches the argument list"

And if I do:

```
pca.operator(matrix);
```

It says "Error: expected an operator". What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"PCA should be initializable by just passing it a matrix."

- no, not true.

[there](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#PCA%3a%3aPCA%28InputArray%20data,%20InputArray%20mean,%20int%20flags,%20int%20maxComponents%29) is neither a single-Mat constructor, nor a single-Mat operator().

you have to supply a data-Mat, a mean-Mat and some flags at least.

Comment: 'optional' means : you can pass an empty `Mat()` , if you do not have a precalculated mean Mat (e.g. from a previous run, as this is an expensive calculation)